# See Edges And Vertices Hidden Behind Mesh That Has A Subdivision Surface Modifier

Tags: vertices, edges, subdivision-surface

I am watching Blender Guru's intermediate tutorial series where he makes an anvil on YouTube. When a subdivision surface modifier is applied, some of the edges and vertices are hidden behind the mesh even though I am looking directly at them in the view. So they aren't hidden on the opposite side of the mesh for example. Some solutions I've found to see them are just using x-ray mode, or by disabling the edit mode view for the subdivision modifier. But I was wondering if there was a way to bring these vertices and edges to the front of the display, without using x-ray mode or disabling the modifier in edit mode. So I want to keep the modifier enabled, but have the vertices and edges show up as if the modifier is disabled(like in the 3rd picture). X-ray mode can be a bit distracting at times since it shows all the vertices, and disabling the modifier makes it harder to see exactly how changing the vertices will affect the mesh with the modifier applied. I made this using Blender version 3.0.0.

Here is the mesh with the subdivision modifier applied:
[image: subdivison modifier applied]

Here is the mesh with the subdivision modifier applied, and with x-ray mode on. Now some edges and vertices that were hidden are revealed:
[image]

Here is the mesh with the subdivision modifier disabled in edit mode:
[image]

Comment: Alas, no.  Those are the only options that you have available.

Comment: @MartyFouts Alright. I'll probably disable the modifier in edit mode and switch to object mode with tab to see how it affects the mesh with the modifier then go back to edit mode.

Comment: The wireframe overlay and wireframe shading mode will reveal the modified edge loops. But the selected vertices & edges are still hidden by the modified geometry. Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZATpN.jpg

Comment: @Blunder when you say wireframe overlay and wireframe shading, do you mean both on at the same time. And to be clear, wireframe shading is found by pressing z then selecting Wireframe? And wireframe overlay is found by clicking the Overlays drop down menu and the selecting the Wireframe checkbox under the Geometry section?

Comment: Yes, wireframe overlay (from the dropdown menu) and wireframe shading (key Z) can do this. But you use either one or the other, not both at the same time. In the screenshot you see the wireframe overlay. I often use it for the sculpt mode to see where the vertices are.

Answer (score 0):

Activate On Cage mode in the Subdivision modifier. Many other modifiers have this On Cage option.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a useful tool that I may use in the future, but it curves the edges on my mesh at some places and they no longer look the same, which isn't a result I want.